# Question about a proof of: If $P$ is a finite $p$-group and $\langle 1\rangle\neq N\trianglelefteq P$, then $N\cap Z(P)\neq\langle 1\rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, group-actions, p-groups

Question: If $P$ is a finite $p$-group and $\langle 1\rangle\neq N\trianglelefteq P$, then $N\cap Z(P)\neq\langle 1\rangle$.

I have a question about a proof I saw in (I believe, Isaacs book).  It goes:
Since $N$ is normal in $P$, $P$ acts by conjugation on $N$ with a set of fixed points in this action precisely $N\cap Z(P)$.  Thus $|N\cap Z(P)|=|N|$ mod $p$. Since $N$ is a non-trivial $p$ group, $|N|=0$ mod $p$, so $|N\cap Z(P)|=0$ mod $p$, hence the result.

My question is how do we know that the set of fixed points in the action is PRECISELY $N\cap Z(P)$?

Comment: It might help to look into proofs of the class equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition $x\in Z(P)$ if and only if $x\in P$ is fixed by the conjugation action of $P$.

Comment: Hi, Sorry to bother you. My name is Keyvan and I am MS student of maths in Iran. I have Algebra course this semester from Hungerford's book and I needed help with my studies and exams but much better than many people I know in Iran your knowledge is great . I was wondering if you could kindly tutor me algebra online for some tuition/rate for which both agree. My email and whatsapp is in my profile. Thank you very much in advance for your help. Kind regards, Keyvan

Comment: @L.G. I'm flattered by your request, but I'm sorry to say that I simply do not have the time. I wish you good luck, at least your professor has good taste in literature :)

Comment: Can you please at least help me out with my exam for two hours maximum?

Answer (score 1):

We know this because $n\in N$ is a fixed point of conjugation by $P$ if and only of $n\in N$ and $pnp^{-1}=n$ for all $p\in P$,  if and only if $n\in N$ and $pn=np$ for all $p\in P$, if and only if $n\in N\cap Z(P)$.